# How can I access BLE Midi device in WPF?

Tags: wpf, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi

I'm looking for a way to implement BLE Midi in WPF, but there seems very little information about it.

I've read this:
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/09/21/midi-enhancements-in-windows-10/

...but it was written 5 years ago and the Win32 wrapper project mentioned in it has been discontinued.

Is there an improved way of accessing Windows.Device.Midi in WPF?

Specifically I want to access a Bluetooth LE (BLE) Midi device.

Comment: Actually you can easy call UWP API from Win32 application by just referencing required assemblies. One of the first link about how to do that: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/

Comment: The other way (for BLE) you con implement all functional by your-self as direct device communication over BLE GATT.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll look into this.